# how to get androiddeployqt on linux

Tags: android, linux, qt

When I try to excute following command :-

```
androiddeployqt --output android --verbose --input android-libQtApp.so-deployment-settings.json -ant
```

I get this error:-

```
zsh: command not found: androiddeployqt
```

these means androiddeployqt is not installed on my machine . How can I get it ?I am using Linux (Manjaro)

Comment: Have you tried using your favourite search engine? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#androiddeployqt says: _Building an application package is complex, so Qt comes with a tool which handles the work for you_ You probably will need to install android support for Qt.

Comment: @AdrianW I read that Link And I have android support for Qt . But that support is not doing its work and I am forced to use terminal .

Comment: You need to add the tool bin location to your $PATH .. check where android packages are installed and it should be there ... normally under `$Qt_Base/android_armv7/bin`

Comment: @MohammadKanan Thanks. I found it in $Qt_Base/android_armv7/bin